Spring test - how to access a mockbean that was configured in a seperate file?
The test file is:
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = BeanTestConfig.class)
class TestWithSeparateBeanConfig {
    @MockBean
    BeanOne beanOne;

    @Autowired
    BeanCollection beanCollection;
    @Test
    void test() {
        when( beanOne.sayHello( any())).thenReturn( "Hello World" );
        assertEquals( "Hello WorldBeanTwo says: Hello ugh", beanCollection.beansSayHello());
    }
}

The simplified test configuration file is:
public class BeanTestConfig {
    @MockBean
    BeanOne beanOne;
    @Bean
    BeanTwo beanTwo() {
        return new BeanTwo();
    }

    @Bean
    BeanCollection beanCollection() {
        return new BeanCollection(List.of( beanOne, beanTwo()));
    }
}

This bean contains a reference to 2 simple beans via the interface:
@Service
public class BeanCollection {
    private final List<MyBeanInterface> beans;

    public BeanCollection(List<MyBeanInterface> beans) {
        this.beans = beans;
    }

    public String beansSayHello() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for( MyBeanInterface bean : beans ) {
            sb.append( bean.sayHello( "ugh"));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}

The beans 'BeanOne' and 'BeanTwo' are like:
@Service
public class BeanOne implements MyBeanInterface {
    @Override
    public String sayHello(String msg) {
        return "BeanOne says: Hello " + msg;
    }
}

How can I perform the mocking in the statement "when( ... )"?
Try 1: In this simplified example I configured the @MockBean in both files. That is of course a 'duplicate mock definition', so will not work.
Try 2: When I use a @Autowired in the test file, I cannot do the mocking.
Try 3: Using @Mock ... gives, of course, no good results because there are 2 different mocks used.

Expected :message
Actual   :nullBeanTwo says: Hello ugh


Try-4: working only with Mockito. Often this is the best and most fast solution.
How to solve this issue? Asking the TestWithSeparateBeanConfig class for access to the 'beanOne' is opening the class for accessing the bean. Which is not a good way of programming.

You want to have @MockBean in your config and @Autowired in your test. That should work, I would think.
